# Navbar shows wrong active element

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Twitter Bootstrap needs this fix in order to not cover the current anchor with the fixed nav-bar

```
legend {
padding-top: 60px;
margin-top: -60px;} /*fixes that anchor element is under navbar*/
```

I use data-spy to highlight the nav menue element

```
<body  data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">
```

Now when I select a navigation element, the element before gets highlighted. I understand that data-spy still sees a spot of the previous element and therefore does highlights the wrong element.

But how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Tell it to the scroll spy script with data attribute `offset`:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">
```